Mysql combine 2 querys
I have a query made by somebody else. Works great, the first query fills an (temporary) table and the 2e querys get's the data from that table.
It should be possible to combine the querys so the temporary table is not needed anymore, but it's not exactly clear to me where to do this.
INSERT INTO TimeTable (group_id, start_time, end_time, duration, available, Room)
SELECT 
    group_id,
    MIN(Timevalue) AS start_time,
    MAX(Timevalue) AS end_time,
    TIMEDIFF(MAX(Timevalue), MIN(Timevalue)) AS duration,
    MAX(Available) AS available_value,
    Room
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Id,
        Timevalue,
        Available,
        PcId,
        Room,
        Job,
        @group := IF(@prev_available <> Available, @group + 1, @group) AS group_id,
        @prev_available := Available AS dummy
    FROM EvertDing where Room = "2.4.19"
    ORDER BY Id
) AS grouped
GROUP BY group_id, Room
ORDER BY group_id;

SELECT 
    Room,
    available,
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration)) AS total_seconds,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration))) AS total_duration
FROM TimeTable where available= 1
GROUP BY room, available;


Learning how to use GROUP BY should be your first step.

If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use a CTE instead of the temp table.

If not, just replace FROM TimeTable with FROM (SELECT ...) where ... is the query you used in the INSERT query. Note that there's no available column in the temp table, it's available_value.

Note also that performance may not be great if you combine the queries. You can add an index to the temp table, but MYSQL doesn't do this automatically for subqueries.

@Eric What's wrong with their use of GROUP BY? It doesn't look like they're violating the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY rule.
